# Alterar campos da tabela User do Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5.4

Estou usando o Laravel no meu TCC e estudo ele por meio de videos e artigos da internet.

Criei a parte de autentificação com o comando make:auth e está funcionando tudo corretamente, mas eu precisaria alterar os campos da tabela User para o padrão do meu projeto.

O nome da tabela eu consegui alterar para Usuarios no arquivo config\auth.php
mas os campos já passei algumas horas pesquisando e todas as informações que encontro são das versões anteriores do Laravel e provavelmente na versão 5.4  a estrutura foi alterada.

As mudanças que preciso são:

```
id > usu_id
name > usu_nome
email > usu_email
password > usu_senha
remember_token > usu_lembrar
```

Desde já agradeço.

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que usar o método table:
Schema::table('nome_seu_banco', function(Blueprint $table){

```
   //O que você for alterar ou incluir na tabela
```

});